# Read file in project directory from native iOS code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I have a react-native application that has some settings in a file called `settings.json`.  I would like to read one of the settings in the file from my native iOS code.  I tried the code below:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *currentpath;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];
NSLog(@"Value of filePath = %@", currentpath);
```

But this logs the path `/` every time.  How can I get the path for my actual project which is something like this: `/Users/currentUser/Documents/development/ReactProject`

I obviously can't hardcode this into my app.  How can I get the directory for the current `react-native` project?

Comment: You want the documents directory, `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want it from your project path either as that's not available to your app under normal circumstances (it's in a sandbox)

The most likely thing I think you want to do is

1. Put the file into your app bundle (just make sure that it's in an Xcode group and assigned to your app target).

Now it will be deployed inside of your app's bundle on whatever device it's on.  It's read-only here.

2. Read it using this:

   ```
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@"json"];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really into React-Native applications but this seems to me an iOS project related problem.
The logged `/` refers to the application folder in this case `/Users/currentUser/Documents/development/ReactProject`.
So try to read the file as a string with:

```
NSString *settings = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings"   ofType:@"json"];
NSLog(@"Content of settings: %@", settings);
```

Make also sure that the file is added to your project and link it to list of files for your target by selecting the right target in the "Target membership" in property of the file as in image.

Hope this helps.

[image: Access to file property by clicking on file]